# calculate rank without using rank or rownums function by using single column

Tags: postgresql

Do not use any functions like rank or rownums.

Hint: Formulate matrix operation using sql. A rank of an item indicates how many items are less than or equal to it.
A matrix can be simulated by cross join and rank can be derived by
counting items smaller than the current item.

Table A:-

```
 x
----
  d
  b
  a
  g
  c
  k
  k
  g
```

Expected output:

```
 x1 | rank
----+------
  a |    1
  b |    2
  d |    3
  g |    4
  c |    5
  k |    6

select x as x1, count(x) as rank
from (select DISTINCT x from A order by x) as sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is on the right track, using a distinct subquery.  For a working version, use a correlated subquery in the select clause which takes counts:

```
SELECT
    x AS x1,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x) FROM A t WHERE t.x <= sub.x) rank
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM A) AS sub
ORDER BY
    x;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo